# Batch processing Stereo to DoubleMono in Adobe Audition

Tags: adobe, audition

Win 7 - Audition CC v11.0.0.199

For my videos I normally record audio through a Behringer Audio Interface. I connect main mono mic to Input 1 and a backup mono mic to Input 2. The result is a stereo audio file in which the left channel is my main mic and the right channel is the backup.

In Premiere I prefer to have a separate "doubled-up" stereo track for each mic. So, for example, my audio track would be my main mic with both L & R channels showing the same signal that originated in the main mic. I only use the other mic as backup.

**I found an easy solution within Premiere... See below "SOLUTION"**

As I record many files in such a way I wish to quickly process them all as batches. I tried both Audacity and Audition and each have their own problems. Let's deal with Audition here:

First I open one audio file. Let's call it "Audio1.wav"

0. Start the favorite recording process (Favorites / Start Recording Favorite) and follow these steps:
1. Edit / Extract channels to Mono Files
   I get two new files Audio1_L & Audio1_R
   On selected file (Audio_R)
2. Edit / Convert Sample Type (Sample Rate: 48000. Channels: Stereo. Bit depth: 32)
3. Save As (keep file name with _R. New folder. Save as .wav). Ok.
   It's saved with the "_R" suffix.
4. Double Clic the other file (Audio1_L)
5. Edit / Convert Sample Type (Sample Rate: 48000. Channels: Stereo. Bit depth: 32)
6. Save As (keep file name with _L. New folder. Save as .wav). Ok.
   It's saved with the "_L" suffix.
7. Close All
   No to All (when asked if I want to save changes)
8. End the favorite recording process (Favorites / Stop recording process) and name it

Ok...

So now I try to use this favorite with just one file as a dry run:

The result is just the same original Audio1 file again!!

What am I doing wrong?

Are there some commands that can't be added as favorites?

What alternatives can I use instead?

Thanks a bunch!!
Miguel

**--SOLUTION--**

I had previously thought I couldn't double a mono track into stereo within Premiere, but I looked into it again and, turns out I can! It's actually quite simple and I can use my original (mixed stereo) file, side stepping Audition altogether.

a. Import "mixed" stereo file into Premiere (say Audio1 as before)

b. Right-click on "mixed" stereo file.

```
- Modify / Audio Channels

- Clip channel format: Stereo

- Number of audio clips: 1

- Select Left Channel "L" for both "L" and "R" in Clip1 (in my case)

- Ok
```

This works for all subsequent uses of the clip, NOT on clips already in the timeline.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hi - can I ask why you want to do this?  If you're recording mono sources, why do you want to convert them to stereo tracks when there is no extra information in the recording?  All you're doing is increasing storage size and processing needed while you work?

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for writing... The reason is that if I leave a track as mono (while the others -music- are stereo) I only hear the voice through one side.

Comment: In any case, I found a much simpler solution within Premiere itself

Comment: You can pan a mono track to the centre of a stereo project

Comment: Thanks! See my main text after --SOLUTION--

Comment: Hi - you should add this as an answer below, so others can see it's been solved

Comment: Sorry! Thanks for reminding me that I need to add the answer in the appropriate section. Newbie mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I had previously thought I couldn't double a mono track into stereo within Premiere, but I looked into it again and, turns out I can! It's actually quite simple and I can use my original (mixed stereo) file, side stepping Audition altogether.

a. Import "mixed" stereo file into Premiere (say Audio1 as before)

b. Right-click on "mixed" stereo file.

- Modify / Audio Channels
- Clip channel format: Stereo
- Number of audio clips: 1
- Select Left Channel "L" for both "L" and "R" in Clip1 (in my case)
- Ok

This works for all subsequent uses of the clip, NOT on clips already in the timeline.

Thanks!!